# Getting Http 403.14 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, configuration

I have a MVC project and trying to host my web site using IIS 7.0 on my local desktop. My desktop has Vista x64 bit machine.

I'm getting 403.14 error. I have already tried the Microsoft suggestion, but that doesn't help me.

Does anyone know any other solution?

Comment: And what did Microsoft suggest?

Comment: Microsoft suggested to change directory browsing to enable, which will just show the directories inside your virtual directory.
And also enable default document in IIS 7.

Answer (score 2):

You may not have the default document specified properly in IIS.  But without details, I can't tell you much more than that.

Comment: What details do you want me to tell you?

Comment: What are the URLs you're using?  Are you attempting to hit up the site with the absolute path or with a directory path?  What are the default document settings in IIS?

Comment: I am trying localhost\wesite.
default.asp,default.aspx and most of the settings are inherited.

Comment: I got it solved.

Then it means .net framework 4 is not installed.
 
So you need to run the following in the Command Prompt/Run as  Administrator
 
And type this command %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30128\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and tried several possible solutions, but none of the worked.  It turns out that I had inadvertently created a directory structure that had the same name as my controller and activity.

For example, I had a URL like `http://localhost:55501/Product/Preview/2` and there was also a Directory like ~/Product/Preview/2.  I would have found it much faster, but I was certain I didn't have a directory named that way.....

So, double check that you don't really have a directory that is named with the same path as the URL.